# ReactJS: How to toggle switch to change background of Web App?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, toggle

I'm trying to build a switch component to toggle the change of dark mode and light mode. I've so far managed to build the switch and allowing it toggle, however, I can't seem to implement the change of background color. I know i will have to set the state with hooks but this is what I have got so far.

Switch Component:

```
const Switch = ({ isOn, handleToggle }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <input
                checked={isOn}
                onChange={handleToggle}
                className='react-switch-checkbox'
                id={`react-switch-new`}
                type='checkbox'
            />
            <label
                className='react-switch-label'
                htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}
                style={{ background: isOn && '#06D6A0' }}
            >
                <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
            </label>
        </>
    )
}
```

Parent Component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false)
<Navbar
    bg='light'
    variant='light'
    expand='lg'
    collapseOnSelect
    className={darkTheme ? 'dark-theme' : 'light-theme'}
>
<Switch
    isOn={value}
    handleToggle={() => setValue(!value)}
    onChange={() => setDarkTheme(prevTheme => !prevTheme)} />
</Navbar>
```

the theme is handled by css. for now, only managed to change the background of the switch itself but not the theme of the webpage. would appreciate any help!

Comment: `Switch` doesn't have `onChange` props ?

Comment: Pass the props in Switch component and also make this change --> `onChange={onChange}`  [checkout the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-star-qg339?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I made the changes proposed, but it's still not changing the theme of the webpage.

Comment: ahh. i think its working now! i placed the child component in the wrong parent component! thank you!! @SarunUK